# What is the Javascript equivalent of $()?

Tags: javascript

**With** jQuery (Selector works)

```
elem = document.getElementById('container');
$(elem).load('file.html');
```

**Without** jQuery (Selector doesn't work)

```
elem = document.getElementById('container');
elem.load('file.html');
```

How can I execute functions on an element without jQuery?

The load() function is **already created** and I'm able to execute the load() function on `$(elem)` but not on `elem`.

Comment: You should probably add how your `load` function is defined. Without one your question has no much sense

Answer (score 2):

`load` is a jQuery function, so without jQuery, it does not exist. But you could create your own:

```
Object.prototype.load = function (src) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        elem = this;
    // Make a request to the provided URL
    request.open('GET', src, true);

    request.onload = function() {
        // When it is loaded
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            // Insert it in the DOM element
            elem.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    };

    request.send();
};

// Example usage
var elem = document.getElementById('container');
elem.load('content.html');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not the load function as I've already created one. It's about the 'elem' selector. I'm able to execute the load function on '$(elem)' but not with 'elem' only.

Comment: @Koen Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell you how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You use the DOM API ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)) and various other [associated APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API). That specific example is rather more work, as you have to query the resource via `XMLHttpRequest` ([spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)), then assign the HTML you've loaded to the `innerHTML` of the element.